# select and deselect checkboxes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

See the following code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    
        $('.checkbox-group .parents-checkbox .panel-title input').click(function () {
        
            $(this).closest('.checkbox-group').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked).closest('label');
        });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default item-box-roll checkbox-group">
        <div class="panel-heading parents-checkbox">
      <h3 class="panel-title">
       <input type="checkbox" name="rolls[]" id="selecctall" value="2" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Items
      </h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body child-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="rolls[]" value="20" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Items management<br>
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="rolls[]" value="21" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add item<br>
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="rolls[]" value="22" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit items<br>
     </div>
    </div>
```

When i click on first checkbox therefore select all checkbox in child-checkbox div. I want to if selected each of checkbox in child-checkbox div then check first checkbox! How can I change the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to listen to the child checkboxes and set the parent checkbox based on whether they have *no unchecked boxes*.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/annvy1ed/1/

```
$('.child-checkbox :checkbox').change(function(){
    $('.checkbox-group .parents-checkbox .panel-title :checkbox').prop('checked', $('.child-checkbox :checkbox').not(':checked').length == 0);
});
```

*The selectors can all be simplified, but this will answer your basic question.*

You can shorten it to:

```
$('.checkbox-group .parents-checkbox .panel-title :checkbox').prop('checked', !$('.child-checkbox :checkbox:not(:checked)').length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/annvy1ed/3/

*You can shorten it a lot more, e.g. if you can make use of your ID selector, but your code indicates you may have multiple groups of checkboxes on the page.*

If there *are* multiple groups you will need to also use `closest` again in the new code:

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/annvy1ed/9/

```
$('.child-checkbox :checkbox').change(function(){
    var $group = $(this).closest('.checkbox-group');
    $group.find('.parents-checkbox .panel-title :checkbox').prop('checked', !$group.find('.child-checkbox :checkbox:not(:checked)').length);
});
```

Notes:

- You should use the `change` event in preference to `click` for checkboxes.
- You can use the `:checkbox` pseudo selector for checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/annvy1ed/2/

**Update "any" child checked:**

If you want to tick the parent if *any* of the child boxes is checked, reverse the logic:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/annvy1ed/5/

```
$('.child-checkbox input').change(function(){
    $('.checkbox-group .parents-checkbox .panel-title input').prop('checked', $('.child-checkbox input:checked').length);
});
```

or, to support multiple checkbox groups:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/annvy1ed/8/

```
$('.child-checkbox :checkbox').change(function(){
    var $group = $(this).closest('.checkbox-group');
    $group.find('.parents-checkbox .panel-title :checkbox').prop('checked', $group.find('.child-checkbox :checkbox:checked').length);
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  For clarification and to ensure this format works even if other types of controls are added to the page, should you add "[input type='checkbox']" to your selector?

Comment: @Stan: I would rework most of the selectors myself, so that everything correctly scoped and group. I am updating the answer at the moment to show other options.

Comment: The target element has ID attribute! I would use it.

Comment: Apart from efficiency, it could make your suggested snippet shorter and more readable. This was the point, not nitpicking! :)

Comment: @Vohuman: I am in the process of making it much neater... Going by the rest of the code however (in a `checkbox-group`) I don't think the ID can be relied upon.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie At first I thank you for your answer. But I want to even if I chose one of the child checkboxes,checked parent checkbox. How do I change the value of length in jquery?

Comment: @rockstar: That is the simpler case... Just test if any is checked. I have added an example above.

Comment: I am newcomer to jquery. in jquery. I would be grateful if you come with some examples.

Comment: @Rockstar: been there, done that... please check for revisions to answer :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Here I got two distinct checkboxes with their own parents and children. I'm gonna check a child of a group and conventionally I should get it's parent checked automatically. And here is the problem: I end up with both parents checked!

Comment: @rockstar: The last example was correct for multiples, but I had the wrong JSFiddle linked. Link now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to check the length

```
$(".checkbox1").change(function(){
    if ($('.checkbox1:checked').length == $('.checkbox1').length) {
       //check the parent checkbox
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tip:** You should use data attributes on your elements to reduce the amount of code and complexity of your JavaScript...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.checkbox-group .parents-checkbox .panel-title input').click(function() {

    $(this).closest('.checkbox-group').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked).closest('label');
  });

  $('.checkbox-group .child-checkbox input').click(function() {
    var total = $('.checkbox-group .child-checkbox input').length;
    var checked = $('.checkbox-group .child-checkbox input:checked').length;

    $('.checkbox-group .parents-checkbox .panel-title input').prop('checked', (total === checked));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default item-box-roll checkbox-group">
  <div class="panel-heading parents-checkbox">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
       <input type="checkbox" name="rolls[]" id="selecctall" value="2" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Items
      </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body child-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="rolls[]" value="20" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Items management
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="rolls[]" value="21" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add item
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="rolls[]" value="22" checked="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit items
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Errrm... *reducing code* would also mean putting `(total === checked)` inside a single prop statement and not duplicate the line :)